# How to set the tornado routing for handler with init parameters?

Tags: python, tornado

I'm building a tornado web server. One of the handler requires init parameters. How to set the routing list so I can pass the values for the paramters?

```
class ActionHandler():
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

    async def post(self, action):
        x = self.p1 
        y = self.p2
        # ....

app = tornado.web.Application([
    ('/action', ActionHandler) # How to pass init parameters?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation notes](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler) that you should not override the `__init__` method of a `RequestHandler` subclass. If you want to pass initial arguments to the handler, use the [`initialze` method](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.initialize).

```
class ActionHandler():
    def initialze(self, p1, p2):
        self.p1 = p1
        self.p2 = p2

# then pass these arguments in a dict 
# when you register the route
app = tornado.web.Application([
    ('/action', ActionHandler, {'p1': 'Hello', 'p2': 'World'}),
])
```